# Will PKCS11 always find objects in the same order?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography, pkcs#11

I have observed that both the bash command and what is probably a corresponding method from the Python PyKCS11 library seem to always find objects in the same order. My code relies on this being true, but have not read it anywhere, just observed it.

In the terminal:

```
$ pkcs11-tool --list-objects 
Using slot 0 with a present token (0x0)
Public Key Object; RSA 2048 bits
  label:      bob_key
  ID:         afe438bbe0e0c2784c5385b8fbaa9146c75d704a
  Usage:      encrypt, verify, wrap
Public Key Object; RSA 2048 bits
  label:      alice_key
  ID:         b03a4f6c375e8a8a53bd7a35947511e25cbdc34b
  Usage:      encrypt, verify, wrap
```

With Python:

```
objects = session.findObjects([(CKA_CLASS, CKO_PUBLIC_KEY)])
for i, object in enumerate(objects):
    d = object.to_dict()
    print(d['CKA_LABEL'])
```

output:

```
bob_key
alice_key
```

`objects` is of type `list` and each element in `objects` is of type `<class 'PyKCS11.CK_OBJECT_HANDLE'>`

Will `session.findObjects([(CKA_CLASS, CKO_PRIVATE_KEY)])` when run from a logged-in session also **always** be a list **with exactly the same order** as the expression above? In this case with two keys, would never want to see Alice come before Bob.

Comment: PKCS#11 is an API, therefore you always have at least two different software components: the API user and the API implementation. Assuming something like and object order is this scenario is IMHO not recommendable. Therefore my advice: if you need a specific order, define your own one based on the labels or some other properties of the entries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Wanted to write a comment, but it got quite long...)

[PKCS#11](https://www.oasis-open.org/standards#pkcs11-base-v2.40) does not guarantee any specific order of returned object handles so it is up to the particular implementation.

Even though your implementation might seem to be consistently giving the same order of objects there are some examples when this could unexpectedly change:

- key renewal (keys do not last forever. You will need to generate some new keys in the future)
- middleware upgrade (newer implementations might return objects in a different order)
- HSM firmware upgrade (major upgrades might change the way objects are stored and change object enumeration order)
- HSM recovery from backup (object order can change after HSM restore)
- host OS data recovery (some implementatins store HSM objects encrypted in external folders and object search order might be the same as directory listing order which could change without a warning)
- HSM change (are you sure that you will be using the same device for the whole lifetime of your application)

Relying on an undefined behaviour in general is a bad practice. Especially in security you should be very cautious.

It is definitely worth the time to stay on the safe side.

---

I would recommend to perform a separate search for each required object (using some strong identifier -- e.g. label) -- this way you can perform additional checks (e.g. enforce expected object type, ensure that object is unique etc.).

---

A similar example is Cryptoki object handle re-use. PKCS#11 states that object handle is bound to particular session (i.e. if you obtained object handle in session A you should not use it in session B -- even if both sessions are running in the same application).

There are implementations that preserve object handle for the same object across sessions. There are even implementations that preserve the same object handle in different applications (i.e. if you get object handle 123 in application A you will get object handle 123 in application B for the same object).

This behaviour is even described in the respective developer manual. But if you ask the vendor if you can rely on it you are told that there are some corner cases for some setups and that you must perform additional checks to be 100% sure that it will work as expected...

Good luck with your project!